# How to access to global static variable in static function having variable with same name

Tags: java

I have a static variable and a local variable in static function with same name. 
In that function how can I access to static variable.

```
static String  s = "class level";
static private void mx(String s)
{
System.out.println(s); // i want class level
}
```

Comment: @Erik: that won't work. It's static and there is no `this`.

Comment: yet beware for missunderstandings: there is no such thing as a global variable in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the name of the class at the left:

```
ClassName.s=...;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use it's full name: `ClassName.s`

Answer (score 2):

Within the function, using just "s" will be the local static variable. To access a static member (function or class) you can call it using

```
Classname.membername
```

In your case, if you wanted to print the local variable, you would use

```
System.out.println(s);
```

as you have rightly done.
Say your entire thing is wrapped in a class called "Test". So,

```
Class Test{
    static String  s = "Global";
    static private void mx(String s)
    {
      System.out.println(s); // i want global
    }
}
```

So, in order to print both the Strings (local s, and "global" s),

```
Class Test{

    static String  s = "Global";
    static private void mx(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);         //prints local s
        System.out.println(Test.s);    //prints "global" s
    }

}
```